# dev drive performance for c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, refs, dev-drive

I'm interested in converting my development partition to a dev-drive. There are a few [benchmarks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/devdrive/) out there for different projects, but not for c++ projects with Visual Studio.

Does anyone have experience with this? What I'm mostly interested in is the build performance (compile and link) of big projects.

Comment: why not just try it and see if it works for you?

Comment: "just try it" will take two days work in my case. I'd like to know if it would be worth it

Comment: I think you will get more value from putting your source code and SDKs on a fast SSD or even a RAM disk, or using more invasive techniques likes unity builds.

Comment: I already use a fast SSD. RamDisk is not an option, would need at least 100GB of RAM for the disk...

Answer (score 0):

From the [blog post with additional details](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/engineering-at-microsoft/dev-drive-and-copy-on-write-for-developer-performance/):

> CoW links, instead of file copies, are an excellent match for any build or tool that:
>
> - Makes explicit file copies to create image layouts, such as for microservice deployments.
> - Uses MSBuild or dotnet for C# builds, as the Resolve Assembly References build task copies .NET assemblies from package directories and parent projects into each new output directory.
> - Uses MSBuild and other items where MSBuild performs a copy recursively in each dependent project. (See Appendix B for ways to change this behavior.)
> - Uses caching build engines and accelerators, such as Microsoft Build Accelerator, that copy files from a local cache directory into the filesystem when a cache hit is processed.

None of this fits particularly well with a typical C++ build process, I'm afraid: dependencies tend to be installed and built globally and the compilation of your own code tends not to be cached or even cachable.